# Install Redux to Angular 2

Tags: angular, redux

I want to install Redux to my Angular2 project, but I'm getting an error message. I'm new to WebApis and Web Coding.

> Unexpected value 'NgReduxModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Show us your full AppModule code

Comment: Yeah. Here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on myself.

I used like my example

```
import { NgRedux, NgReduxModule } from 'ng2-redux';
```

but right is

```
import { NgRedux, NgReduxModule } from '@angular-redux/store';
```

Thanks to all who read and want to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my package.json. There is another file named package-lock.json.

```
    {
  "name": "Portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "@angular/cli": {
    "version": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.5.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-platform-node": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.29",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "node": "0.0.0",
    "preboot": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.0.0",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```